# PowerShell - difference between entries in $Error, a cmdlet does not expose internal code, but function does

Tags: powershell

Can anyone please explain to me the difference between what I see in `$Error` when I encounter errors in `Connect-MSOLService` (as an example), and a custom PowerShell function. Specifically, why the former does not expose the internal code that caused an exception, while the latter does.

Hopefully the examples below help demonstrate what I mean...

```
Connect-MSOLService

PS C:\Users\robert> Connect-MsolService
Connect-MsolService : Authentication Error: Unexpected authentication failure.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-MsolService
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService

PowerShell function

Connection failed to host google.com
At line:31 char:9
+         throw [System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], AuthenticationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connection failed to host google.com
```

Note that the error I see in the console does not expose the internal code. It is only when I look in the `$Error` variable.

Comment: PowerShell only knows the internals of commands _implemented in PowerShell_. `Connect-MsolService` appears to be a _cmdlet_, i.e. a command implemented via an assembly (a `*.dll` file), typically compiled from C#.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I thought it might be something like that, but I had to know the answer!

Comment: Agree with above.  Also note that you are displaying the TEXT output of the Error and not the actual object. PS errors are objects in their own right so piping them to Format-Object -full * can be useful. Also looking within selected subobjects.  Another point, PowerShell errors aren't always "errors" but are sometimes "exceptions" and therefore have a different structure which makes coding for the internals a nuisance.

Answer (score 0):

mklement0's comment answered this for me.